# Caching actions in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, optimization

I want to cache an action and I want it to be different depending on a request param ('type').

How can I do that? I want that not only the rendering will be cached, but also the calculation and the DB requests (most of the action itself)

One possible solution would be to save the different results to a file and once created to redirect to a proxy actions for each type and render them, but that it overly complicated solution and maybe Rails has a better build-in solution.

Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `before filter` to check the param type and proceed with necessary action.

```
before_filter :check_params, :only => :some_action
caches_action :some_action

def check_params
  if params["type"] == 'something'
    query_method1
  else
    query_method2
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a progress but then the action :some_action will get cached using an arbitrary query method and not per type